# Xcode Update Sqlite Record

Tags: ipad, sqlite, sql-update

i have a problem with updating my sqlite database so i would be very grateful if anyone could help me. I tried with every possible example and tutorial but nothing. In my sqlite table i have 9 attributes, but i need to update only three .

```
const char *sql = "UPDATE studentNotes SET title = ? , note = ? , existingAudioNote = ? , audioNoteName = ? , audioNoteDuration = ? , existingPdf = ? , pdfFileName = ? WHERE id = ?";

if(sqlite3_open([[AppDelegate getDatabasePath]UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    else {

        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [noteTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 2, [noteText UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 3, [noteExistingAudioNote UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 4, [noteAudioName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 5, [audioNoteDuration UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 6, [existingPdf UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 7, [pdfFileName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt)){
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }


        sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);
    }
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

i tried with this code, but when i call this method from my class to the view, it doesnt work. Any ideas ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sqlite3 update not working in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439751/sqlite3-update-not-working-in-ios) and many more, can't imagine why it is so hard to do a Google search before posting...

Comment: Could you be a little more specific than "doesnt work"?

Comment: When i try to update record, it doesnt do anything. There are no errors shown up. Up the only thing that it does is recording the same record again. I found that problem in appdelegate at addObject: . I tried even with the Coffe tutorial but nothing. The only think that is saw is that i doesnt get it's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` command has eight parameters, but you set only the first seven.
The last parameter still has its default value, which means that what gets executed is:

```
UPDATE ... WHERE id = NULL
```

which does not match any record (because `NULL` cannot be compared with `=`).

Comment: I'm gonna try to edit the update statement, but can you tell me what is the best place to call the methods? Directly on the button or? Because i created in AppDelegate -(void)updateRecord:(NotesMainClass*)notesObject { [notesObject updateData]; [notesDatabase addObject:notesObject];